Tensor of structs / multi-dimensional data structure of structs in mojo
I need a data strucuture that is a 2-dimensional array of lists of pairs. That is, if subdata = data[i][j], then subdata is a dynamic data structure that contains tuples of size 2.
My take on solving this was to use a Tensor for the 2-D data structure, an InlinedFixedVector for the flexible part, and a StaticTuple for the pair.
from tensor import Tensor
from collections import InlinedFixedVector
from utils import StaticTuple


struct MyStruct:
    var data: Tensor[InlinedFixedVector[StaticTuple[Float64, 2], 10]]

However, I get the following error:
'Tensor' parameter #0 has 'DType' type, but value has type 'AnyStruct[InlinedFixedVector[StaticTuple[SIMD[float64, 1], 2], 10]]'

Can Tensors only hold trivial data types? If so, is there a good general data structure for multi-dimensional data? Are the other data structures good choices for what I need?
